# `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- rvm/capistrano (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm, capistrano

I'm on **Ubuntu 12.04**, **Ruby 1.9.3**, **Rails 3.2.8** using **RVM**.

Yesterday i used Capistrano just fine, i restarted my ubuntu and now i'm when i'm trying to deploy with capistrano i get this:

```
$ cap deploy
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- rvm/capistrano (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:152:in `require'
    from ./config/deploy.rb:4:in `load'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:172:in `load_from_file'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:89:in `load'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `load'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `load'
    from Capfile:5:in `load'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:172:in `load_from_file'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:89:in `load'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `load'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `load'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:65:in `load_recipes'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:65:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:65:in `load_recipes'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:31:in `execute!'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:14:in `execute'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/bin/cap:4
    from /usr/local/bin/cap:19:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/cap:19
```

Here is my PATH variable:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/danpe/.rvm/bin
```

Any ideas?

Comment: well it's looking in the 1.8 folder are you sure that the RVM is loaded? do a `ruby -v` in terminal to see what version is running. I'm guessing that you need to do `rvm use 1.9.3` and need to set the default to be 1.9.3 with `rvm --default 1.9.3`

Comment: Yup, it works, wanna post it as answer?
rvm --default 1.9.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you rebooted you lost the ruby 1.9.3 setup using rvm. To get it back and set it as the default (reboot proof) do:

```
rvm --default 1.9.3
```